# Upgrade to v3 log list to prevent app crashes for "com.appmattus.certificatetransparency"

Tags: android, google-play-console

[image]

I am getting the following message on Google Play console regarding my one of the live apps. PFA regarding message. I have searched my whole project and modules in Android project but still unable to find the which SDK/ third party library is using `com.appmattus.certificatetransparency`. Please guide me regarding below question:

1. How to find the exact module/ SDK using  `com.appmattus.certificatetransparency`?
2. What will be the impact? If I don't upgrade my mentioned version from V2 to V3. Will it cause crashes on front end app?

Waiting for kind response.

I have searched the for the third party SDKs and modules in android project, if any SDK is using this `com.appmattus.certificatetransparency` but I'm unable to find it.